# Installation directory blender on a MAC

Tags: osx

I want to run an application that needs to know the blender installation directory on a mac. I have tried a lot but somehow I have not the very specific directory name. Who can give me this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you download a compressed folder, extract it and put it into the `Applications` folder. There's no real installation involved since all data is stored inside this folder which can be stored anywhere. So on mac the directory of Blender is individual on each system.

The actual executable can be found within the `Blender.app` application bundle. Right click, select `Show Package Contents` and navigate to `Contents/MacOS/` where the unix executable can be found (if the executable is what you're looking for). You can now drag&drop this file into the terminal to get the full path.

If the only purpose is to access blender from a program locally, this may suffice. If you plan to make your program available for others, some more steps would be involved like prompting the user to specify a path to blender.

Comment: thanks. but how would you write down the path for the directory ? This application wants to know the exact path where the blender directory can be found

Comment: @OldMan Hmm..not sure if I understand your question, but I would just drag&drop the executable into the terminal, copy the path and paste it where it's needed. That should give you something like `/Applications/blender/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender`. It's hard to tell without knowing what your program expects.